# How to understand that function / pointer declaration?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

In C, one can declare pointers to functions like that:

```
void (*Func1)(int)
```

I believe that I've understood what this means (in this case, a pointer to a function which returns `void` and takes an `int` as parameter) and how to declare and use such pointers.

However, I now have come across declarations like the following:

```
void (*Func2(int, int))(int)
```

I am struggling with understanding this syntax. What exactly is declared here? Probably it is a pointer to a function, but I always thought that the closing round parenthesis after the pointer's name is necessary then, so I am completely unsure now.

Could anybody explain, step by step, what the above declaration means?

Comment: Perhaps it is a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a function.

Comment: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) ==> *declare Func2 as function (int, int) returning pointer to function (int) returning void* or, in my words, `Func2()` returns a function pointer.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about cdecl.org - already have bookmarked it.

Comment: Perhaps it's best understood with the "declaration mirrors use" rule. The declaration is trying to look like how you could use it. E.g. `(*Func2(1,2))(3)` is a valid call, and the return type of that call is void.

Comment: Excellent explanation - thanks a lot! Got it now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*Func2%28int%2C+int%29%29%28int%29

> void (*Func2(int, int))(int)

> declare Func2 as function (int, int) returning pointer to function (int) returning void

Comment: Thanks. Can't upvote yet, but will accept as soon as possible (must wait 10 minutes obviously ...)